# Why does PHP print a percent sign when my script is done?

Tags: php, macos, terminal

When I run a simple `echo 'Hello World';` script in PHP from my terminal on my Mac, I see a percent sign (`%`) appear at the end of the line.

Why is this? Can I disable this?

```
~ php -r "echo 'Hello World';"
Hello World%                                          
~
```

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Technically, I'm not doing this in bash, I'm running [**Oh My Zsh**](http://ohmyz.sh/), if that matters.

Comment: It's not coming from PHP (at least not directly). It's likely your shell has decided to show the EOL character as a percent sign.

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/a/645612/500502

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is from zsh.

Your output doesn't end with a line break. Bash would start the PS1 right after your output, zsh prints a (colored) % and insert a line break itself. You can prevent it by adding a line break yourself

```
php -r 'echo "Hello World\n";'
```

Note: I switched " and ', in php '\n' would print it as is but "\n" means line break.

Comment: Figured it was some EOL thing, but your explanation makes perfect sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding a line to echo PHP_EOL in the end also helps.

```
echo PHP_EOL;
```

[Example PHP code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nEA6.png)

[Related output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el3vj.png)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to .zshrc :

```
PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''
```

It's work for me.

For detail explanation you can go here: https://superuser.com/a/645612

Comment: I would recommend against hiding this. It's useful to know when data is being outputted without a new line. It's also easy enough to append ```'&& echo ""``` to any command that isn't returning a new line.